# In my component add new Item is not working in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

All files are attached as below,

1. component.html - This is component file
2. component.ts - This is component ts file
3. admin-service - This is service file
4. admin.ts - This is model file

**add-que.html** - This is component html file.

```
<div>
    <form [formGroup]="adminForm" (ngSubmit)="newQuestion()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Question</label>
            <input formControlName="description" type="description" placeholder="Enter question"
                class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            <small class="text-danger"
                *ngIf="!adminForm.get('description').valid && adminForm.get('description').touched">
                Please Enter a Question</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-auto">
            <div class="col-6">
                (a)<input formControlname="alternatives" type="text">
                (b)<input formControlname="alternatives" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                (c)<input formControlname="alternatives" type="text">
                (d)<input formControlname="alternatives" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-auto">
            <input type="submit" value="Add"  class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </div>
          
    </form>
</div>


**add-que.ts** - This is component ts file.

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminService } from '../service/admin.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-question',
  templateUrl: './add-question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-question.component.css']
})
export class AddQuestionComponent implements OnInit {

  adminForm = new FormGroup({
    description: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
    alternatives: new FormControl("", [Validators.required])
  });
  constructor(private adminService: AdminService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  newQuestion(){
    if(this.adminForm.valid){
      this.adminService.addQue(this.adminForm.value).subscribe(res => {
        this.adminForm.reset();
        this.router.navigate(["/admin"]);
      })
    }
  }
}


**admin-service.ts** - This is service ts file.

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Admin } from "../model/admin";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminService {
  private ROOT_URL =  "http://localhost:3300/questions";

  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json")   
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getQuestion(): Observable<Admin[]> {
    return this.http.get<Admin[]>(this.ROOT_URL);
  } 
  getQue(id: string){
    return this.http.get<Admin>(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${id}`);
  }

  addQue(admin){
    return this.http.post<any>(this.ROOT_URL, admin, this.httpOptions);
  }
}


**admin.ts** - This is model ts file.

export interface Admin {
    description: String,
    alternatives: [
        {
            text: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            isCorrect: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: true,
                default: false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I did created add-question component with form as above. I did tried to add new question through form in angular but not get anything. i did attached my files as above.

Comment: Angular code looks fine, did you check the server running at port 3300 about the response it sends back to POST requests? Since the `getQuestion()` method is called to obtain the updated results from the server - you may have to verify what you get as response after you've added the question.

Comment: what do you mean you dont get anything and what above components contain ? we cant see them

Comment: @Neelavar I did checked server run on port 3300 and i did already test api with post man it's work. but when i submit question with options on form there i not get anything as output and not redirect to listing component. i want to add that questions on listing component.

Comment: @Teoman Tıngır  I mean to say i created above files. in this i want to add question through form and on submit that will be redirect to listing question component and saved their.

Answer (score 0):

you sould'nt use `this.router.navigate(["/admin"]);` to try "refresh a component". That's no work (there are no changes). In general you has a component with a ngOnInit. Simply get out the code under a ngOnInit in a function and call this function in subscribe, e.g.

```
ngOnInit()
{
    this.init()
}
init()
{
   ..here you initialize your variables
}
submit(){
  ...
  .subscribe(res=>{
       ....
       this.init()
  })
}
```